# Package hyperref Warning: I think because of Co-author

Tags: hyperref, author

I am getting three errors:

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `<def>-command' on input line 51.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\cnotenum' on input line 51.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `@corref' on input line 51.

Which I think because of the Corresponding Authors, I am using elsevier template. I don't know why I am getting all three emails under the Corresponding author even though I only have one Co-Author!

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%Elsevier template %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}

\journal{Energy}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
%\usepackage[round, sort & compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

 
\begin{frontmatter}
%% Title, authors and addresses

  \author[aa,ab]{Author1 S}
 \ead{author1@gmail.edu}
 
 \author[ab]{Author2 H}
 \ead{author2@gmail.edu}
 
 \author[ab]{Author3 r\corref{cor}}
 \ead{author3@gmail.edu} 
 \cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

 \address[aa]{Department of Latex 1 Engineering, University of Latex 1}
 \address[ab]{Department of Latex 2 Engineering, University of Latex 2} 
 
\begin{abstract}
 Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex    
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
Latex Latex Latex  Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex.



\end{document}

\endinput
```

Comment: you are getting warnings, not errors. And they only affect the pdfinfo entry, not the output. Use `\hypersetup{pdfauthor=whatever}` to set the pdfauthor entry, then hyperref will not longer try to use the content of the \author command.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help